# AWS - SageMaker Serverless Inference with SageMaker Neo

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am planning to use SageMaker Serverless Inference in conjunction with SageMaker Neo to deploy my model for serverless, low latency inference. However, documentation is not clear whether it is possible to do so.

According to Instance Types for Neo [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/neo-supported-cloud.html), I can use e.g. `ml_m4` instance. However, OutputConfig for Neo Compiler [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_OutputConfig.html) specifies that TargetDevice can be `lambda`. Serverless Inference [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/serverless-endpoints.html) specify that "Serverless Inference integrates with AWS Lambda to offer you high availability...", so I assume that underlying instances are of the same (or compatible) type with AWS Lambda.

1. Have you used such combination? Does it work?
2. Which instance type should I compile for with Neo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently not an integration between Serverless Inference and Neo. AWS Lambda and SageMaker Serverless Inference are separate features. Lambda is its own service and that's why it's a compatible option for the TargetDevice. SageMaker Serverless Inference is a hosting option on SageMaker that integrates with Lambda.